# Regex101.com and Chrome output are different

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

Hi I'm so new to regex.

I tried `([&|!]?\d+)` in [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/S6oCwT/1) for input string `17&7&(!8|25)` and got the right result, hence the regex101's result is correct (you can refer. But the same expression in Google Chrome out puts quite different).

In both the flags are `igm`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: `"17&7&(!8|25)".match(/([&|!]?\d+)/igm);` results in `["17", "&7", "!8", "|25"]` for me in chrome console. Seems like the expected value. No repro?